# Batch script stops after output conda environment

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, anaconda

I'm trying to write a batch script to export all available conda evnironments, after searching piece by piece on the internet, I came up with the following:

```
@echo off

conda info --envs > conda_envs.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("conda_envs.txt") do (
    if not %%a==# conda env export -n %%a > %%a.yml
)
```

The problem is that the script stops after `conda info --envs > conda_envs.txt`, I've tried to add `call` in front of both the `for` loop and `export` command, but no luck. What did I do wrong?

Comment: are there any error messages?

Comment: Nop, just as if you had it executed successfully,  no message at all

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthese `)` to close the `for` loop. Testing with a [preset file](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/getting-started.html#managing-python) fails with the `for` loop until the closing parentheses is added.

Comment: I have a theory, but I can't test it - put `call` in front of `conda`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the missing parentheses, updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [npocmaka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388389/npocmaka), [michael_heath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9012170/michael-heath) and [SomethingDark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4158862/somethingdark) in the comment section, I think the missing parentheses made the debug process harder. By adding `call` in front of `conda` does help! Below is a working version of the script:

```
@echo off

call conda info --envs > conda_envs.txt

for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims= " %%a in ("conda_envs.txt") do (
    if not %%a==# call conda env export -n %%a > %%a.yml
)
```

PS: if the second `call` before `conda env export...` is not added, this would work as well.